# How to upload MultipartFormData with authentication using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

How to upload `MultipartFormData` with authentication using Alamofire? The part that I don't understand is where to put `.authenticate(user: username, password: password).`? This is how I usually upload pictures using `MultipartFormData`:

```
Alamofire.upload(
        .POST, "https://myExampleUrl/photo/upload", headers: headers, multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: "default".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"_formname")
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: fileUrl, name: "photo")
        },
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {

            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseString { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                }

            case .Failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }
    )
```

I think it's possible to add authentication process into headers?

Comment: I usually have the user authenticate first and then send in the header the session token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't had much time to explore the API for `rilbits.com`. When I visited the address in Safari, I got the following error:

```
Please add 'Authorization' or 'X-Access-Token' header to your request
```

This suggests 2 options for you:

1. Login first and get back an access token, which you can then use the for the upload request
2. Send a basic `Authorization` header along with the upload request.

Here's how you can send the `Authorization` header (second option):

```
let username = "username"
let password = "password"

let credentialData = "\(username):\(password)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!                  
let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
let headers = ["Authorization": base64Credentials]

Alamofire.upload(
    .POST,
    "https://rilbits.com/supersafe/photo/upload",
    headers: headers,
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        let data = "default".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: data, name: "_formname")
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: fileURL, name: "photo")
    },
    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {

        case .Success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseString { response in
                debugPrint(response)
            }

        case .Failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
)
```

Full disclosure:

- The authorization code was lifted from Alamofire's [readme](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/README.md#http-basic-authentication)
- I didn't test the code above

Comment: This is not work in swift 3.0. Any suggestion for swift 3.0 ?

Comment: This no longer works in the latest version (4.0) of Alamofire. Because the header parameters in the upload function is no longer there. Any ideas please?

Comment: how about audio file in Alamofire 4? - i try to send a audio file in this form : multipartFormData.append(audioLocalPath, withName: "file", fileName: "file", mimeType: "application/octet-stream") but occur this error : multipartEncodingFailed(Alamofire.AFError.MultipartEncodingFailureReason.bodyPartFileNotReachableWithError(file:///var/mobile/Containers/....... /Documents/item.mp3, NSUnderlyingError=0x16049100 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}})) - where is problem? -bad request or bad audio path?

Comment: @JayVDiyk At 4.4.0, it seems the parameter is back again.

Answer (score 1):

`Alamofire.upload` does not really upload here: it only writes the multi-part request into a file.

When you call `.responseX` on `upload` in `encodingCompletion`, *that's* when the request is actually performed. That is,

```
upload.authenticate(user: username, password: password)
      .responseString { ...}
```

should do what you want.

If you authenticate with headers, setting the `headers` parameter of `Alamofire.upload` should still work; as far as I can tell, it should forward the headers to `upload`. You can verify that by dumping `upload` to the console, and you can also set headers to `upload` as you would for normal requests.